# Open CL Materials and hardware support required

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl, gpu

I have just started to learn open CL,

1.can any body suggests any good links and materials to start learning OpenCL from scratch.

2.Which SDK to use to run Open CL program,without any hardware constraints.

3.I dont have any hardware,can i run OpenCL program on i7.

Your comments will be great help to me.

Comment: See this answer to the related question 'A nice starter kit for opencl'  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939589/a-nice-starter-kit-for-opencl/9338261#9338261

Comment: I order to use OpenCL on your CPU, you should download either the AMD APP SDK or Intel's OpenCL SDK.  The AMD one supports a wide range of Intel and AMD CPUs so I would start with that one.